# Is there a way to use variable keys in a JavaScript object literal?

Tags: javascript

I have code like this.

```
var key = "anything";   
var object = {   
    key: "key attribute"  
};
```

I want to know if there is a way to replace that `key` with "anything".

like

```
var object = {  
    "anything": "key attribute"     
};
```

Answer (score 336, accepted):

In ES6, use **[computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)**.

```
const key = "anything";   

const object = {   
    [key]: "key attribute"
//  ^^^^^  COMPUTED PROPERTY NAME
};
```

Note the square brackets around `key`. You can actually specify any expression in the square brackets, not just a variable.

Comment: That's fine for ES6 but what about older versions (IE11 will crash on the code above)

Answer (score 128):

Yes.  You can use:

```
var key = "anything";
var json = { };
json[key] = "key attribute";
```

Or simply use your second method if you have the values at hand when writing the program.

Answer (score 32):

On modern Javascript (ECMAScript 6) you can sorround the variable with square brackets:

```
var key = "anything";

var json = {
    [key]: "key attribute"
};
```

Answer (score 16):

This should do the trick:

```
var key = "anything";

var json = {};

json[key] = "key attribute";
```

Comment: But he wants to do this in the context of an object literal.

Answer (score -2):

Recently needed a solution how to set cookies passing the dynamic json key values.
Using the https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie#json, it can be done easily.
Wanted to store each selected option value of user in cookie, so it's not lost in case of tab or browser shutting down.

```
var json = { 
        option_values : {}
    };
    $('option:selected').each(function(index, el) {
        var option = $(this);
        var optionText = option.text();
        var key = 'option_' + index;
        json.option_values[key] = optionText;
        Cookies.set('option_values', json, { expires: 7 } );
    });
```

**Then you can retrieve each cookie key value on each page load using**

```
Cookies.getJSON('option_values');
```

Answer (score -3):

Well, there isn't a "direct" way to do this...

but this should do it:

```
json[key] = json.key;
json.key = undefined;
```

Its a bit tricky, but hey, it works!

Answer (score -3):

Closures work great for this.

```
function keyValue(key){
  return function(value){
    var object = {};
    object[key] = value;
    return object;
  }
}

var key = keyValue(key);
key(value);
```

Comment: Closure is merely the mechanism used here. The concept is HOF.

Comment: HOF = Higher Order Functions.