# Using an Object as key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a questionnaire builder where the answers to some questions can lead to follow-up questions. The next step is to serialize this data and process it into a SQL query. Even though I'm using jQuery, I don't think `serializeArray()` is complex enough to serialize the data in the way I want, which would be like:

```
Answer = {
    'text': String,
    'default': String,
    'img_path': String
}

Question = { 
    'type': String,
    'text': String,
    'followups': {
        Answer : [Question, Question, ...],
        Answer : [Question],
        Answer : []
    }
}
```

The problem I'm running into is that when I try to use an `Answer` object as a key in the `'followups'` map--when I use `JSON.stringify()`, rather than stringifying the key, it is outputted as [object Object].

EDIT:

Stringifying the key is one way to keep the data, but then there are some nasty escapes, e.g.

```
"followups": {
    "{\"text\":\"asdfasdfa\"}": []
}
```

It'd be nice to fix this, but I'm open to any recommendations on a better way of serializing this form.

Comment: a key in a JSON object can only be made out of strings. You can try adding another object of answers (using IDs or whatever) and use the Answer id to construct the followups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to modify your data structure slightly, something similar to this:

```
Question = { 
    'type': String,
    'text': String,
    'followups': [
        {
            answer : Answer,
            questions : [Question, Question, ...]
        },
        {
            answer : Answer,
            questions : [Question]
        },
        {
            answer : Answer,
            questions : []
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: In this case, Question.followups should be an array, not an object

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882727/is-a-way-that-use-var-to-create-json-object-in-key

I interpreted that as being able to use any type of variable as a key; but thanks for your help!