# How to use a String variable as key in a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Is a way that use var to create JSON object in key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882727/is-a-way-that-use-var-to-create-json-object-in-key)

I would like to construct a JSON object in JavaScript by using the value of a (String) variable as the key. But what I got is the name of the variable as the key.

example.js:

```
function constructJson(jsonKey, jsonValue){
   var jsonObj = { "key1":jsonValue, jsonKey:2};
   return jsonObj;
}
```

The call

```
constructJson("key2",8);
```

returns a JSON -> {"key1":8,"jsonKey":2} but I would like to have {"key1":8,"key2":2}.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?
seems like a simple problem but I cannot find the solution.

Comment: sorry for duplicate question... found awnser here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/882749/1005072

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
function constructJson(jsonKey, jsonValue){
   var jsonObj = {"key1": jsonValue};
   jsonObj[jsonKey] = "2";
   return jsonObj;
}
```