# Referencing a JSON key with Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, json

How do I replace the "Argentina" key with a javascript variable string?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $.getJSON('countries.json', function(data) {

        var output= data.Argentina[0].countryPhone1;

        alert(output);

     });
});
```

Here's what my .json data file looks like:

```
{
    "Argentina": [{
        "countryName":"Argentina",
        "countryPhone1":"1234"
    }],

    "Brazil": [{
        "countryName":"Brazil",
        "countryPhone1":"5678"
    }]
}
```

I tried applying the suggested solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13833204/how-to-set-a-json-key-from-a-variable), [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCQQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F10055919%2Fjquery-json-how-to-define-key-from-variable&ei=HjnqVP7LKc_9gwSo84KAAg&usg=AFQjCNH6UkRnjeeGPeb7I4uybrGHx1hRBw&sig2=EQeYO8eREUq0O_thZHIjIw&bvm=bv.86475890,d.eXY) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474040/how-to-use-a-string-variable-as-key-in-a-json-object), but I couldn't figure out a way to adapt them to my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myString = 'Argentina';  /* or whatever you like */

var output = data[myString][0].countryPhone1;
```