# use variables as keys in multi level json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON object called `arrayToSubmit`. Here is the following code:

```
location = "Johannesburg, South Africa";
type = "bench";
qty = 1;
assetNumber = 15;

arrayToSubmit = {
    location : {
        type : {
            'qty' : qty,
            'assetNumber' : assetNumber
        }
    }
}
```

But the result in chrome is as follows:

```
Object{location { type : {"qty" : "1", "assetNumber" : "15"}}}
```

I need to replace the words location and type with the variables in the initial code, like this:

```
Object{"Johannesburg, South Africa" = { "bench" = {"qty" - "1", "assetNumber" : "15"}}}
```

(I am pulling these values from my page, I just typed them out here for ease of use).

**I have already tried these two examples, but don't know how to get it in multi level format.**

[is a way that use var to create json object in key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882727/is-a-way-that-use-var-to-create-json-object-in-key)

[how to set a json key from a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13833204/how-to-set-a-json-key-from-a-variable)

Comment: arrayToSubmit is an object, not a JSON object.

Comment: I guess you couldn't figure out how to refer to the "location" property after setting it? Like so: `var data = {}; data[location] = {}; data[location][type] = {...};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), like this

```
var arrayToSubmit = {};

arrayToSubmit[location] = {};
arrayToSubmit[location][type] = {
  'qty': qty,
  'assetNumber': assetNumber
};
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. I didnt figure out bracket notation before as I missed the line `arrayToSubmit[location] = {};`.

Comment: @VaMoose: The question you linked to already explains the exact same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/882749/218196. Using bracket notation is the solution, how could you have missed that? *edit:* Or did you mean you forgot to create the object? I mean, you cannot just do `var foo; foo[bar] = '...';` either, you have to create the object first.

Comment: @FelixKling I used bracket notation, I just didnt figure out how to do it **properly**, I missed the `{}` when creating the variable.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [] operator to use a variable value as a key. When declaring properties inside the object initializer {} the keys are always literal.

You do it like this :

```
var location = "Johannesburg, South Africa";
var objectToSubmit = {};
objectToSubmit[location] = {...};
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code:

```
arrayToSubmit = {};
obj = {};
obj[type] = {
            'qty' : qty,
            'assetNumber' : assetNumber
        };
arrayToSubmit[location] = obj;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not use 'location', it will interfere with window.location variable.

```
arrayToSubmit = {};
arrayToSubmit[loc] = {};
arrayToSubmit[loc][type] = {
    'qty' : qty,
    'assetNumber' : assetNumber
};
```

Comment: I missed that! Changing it now. Thanks !