# Jquery Animate Left or Right by variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say I have the following function

```
function slide(element, direction, hide){
    if (direction == "left") {
        $(element).animate({
            "left": 500,
        }, 500, function(){
            if(hide) {
                $(element).css("display", "none");
            }
        });
    } else {
        $(element).animate({
            "right": 500,
        }, 500, function(){
            if(hide) {
                $(element).css("display", "none");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

which works great by itself. But I would like to eliminate the If else term to get something like this

```
function slide(element, direction, hide){
    $(element).animate({
        direction : 500,
    }, 500, function(){
        if(hide) {
            $(element).css("display", "none");
        }
    });
}
```

Which doesnt work at all... Is there any way to control left/right by variable in animate function?

Comment: In `direction : 500,`, the variable will not be parsed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882727/is-there-a-way-that-use-var-to-create-json-objects-with-a-key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a object yourself with direction and then use it in animate function like following.

```
function slide(element, direction, hide) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[direction] = 500;

    $(element).animate(obj, 500, function () {
        if (hide) {
            $(element).css("display", "none");
        }
    });
}
```